# Convert RTF from URL to HTML

Tags: perl, rtf, lwp

I have tried to convert RTF to HTML using the Perl library `RTF::HTML::Converter`. All works fine under a console and when source is located as a local path but when I have tried to access that file via URL it brings regular RTF not HTML

My code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use RTF::HTML::Converter;
use LWP::Simple;        

my $url = "http://somesite.com/docs/example_file.rtf";
my $htmlOut;
my $content = get($url);
my $object = RTF::HTML::Converter->new( output => \$htmlOut);
$object->parse_stream($content); 

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";    
print $htmlOut;
```

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong? Also how can I get displayed HTML output instead to `STDOUT`? Trying to output to the browser I'm getting that error:

`malformed header from script. Bad header=<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" []>`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.
The output of RTF::HTML::Converter seems, with the examples I tried, to be perfectly valid HTML.
The 'malformed header' seems to indicate you are not setting a correct header. How about using a modern web framework?

Comment: @bytepusher we don't know if the OP controls the remote server. It sounds like they don't, but have verified that the conversion part is working as expected when run locally. They might not have understood what the error means and where it comes from though.

Comment: I need to parse RTF email attachments for a "preview" (in an iframe). No clue why but I get two headers - first correct one from the `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";` and then second one from parsed HTML. I have read that `RTF::HTMLConverter` may be better choice but I don't know why I can't install `XML::GDOME` which is required by that library.

Comment: So you are not using RTF::HTMLConverter, but some other code is producing incorrect headers?
Regarding the installation, you may want to post a different question to get help with that.

Comment: @bytepusher `RTF::HTML::Converter` and `RTF::HTMLConverter` are two different libs